# Android manage relative layout alignment

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment

I designed one layout with 3 button, I want to manage separator's alignment. here my xml layout ,

```
<RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/menuLayout1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp" 

                    >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_Menu"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:background="#00000000"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/menu"
                        android:text="@string/menu"
                        android:textColor="@color/restaurant_list_menu_font"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="5dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_Menu"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" 
                        android:background="@drawable/sep" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_Review"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:background="#00000000"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/reviews"
                        android:text="@string/pages"
                        android:textColor="@color/restaurant_list_menu_font"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="5dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_page"
                        android:background="@drawable/sep"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                         />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_page"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:background="#00000000"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/pages"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/reviews"
                        android:textColor="@color/restaurant_list_menu_font"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </RelativeLayout>
```

I want to manage View with center of 2 button 
here is Current output[image]

3 buttons are managed but I also want to manage alignment of this separator image..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the separator image as your background, add an imageView to the views, make the view fill the entire gap and center that imageview in the parent. For as far as I know, there is no option on how the background should be positioned i a view.

Another way is to put them all in a Linear Layout, use imageViews instead of Views and use weights to position them correctly.

Comment: thanks for answer Andy. I just tried out Image view instead of view, but couldn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try using nested layout ,so that you can manage each one separately

Comment: thanks abhilash for answer, let me know I have to use either linear or RelativeLayout layout for each button and view?

Comment: I would prefer relative layout